# Dragging more information into an existing event

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am looking to FullCalendar for a full shift/rota system in our application. I have been able to copy external events in to the calendar which has worked great, however I would like to be able to drag in more information into that specific event.

Say I have a shift from 08:00 to 16:00, I will drag that shift into the FullCalendar control. I would then like to be able to assign staff to that event. So dragging a staff member into that event will then update the database and re-render the calendar with a bigger description and with that staff member as a value in extendedProps.

Does anyone know if this is possible at all?

Comment: I don't know if you can do it by dragging specifically, but certainly you can associate more data with an event. But you need to write your own GUI controls to do it. Is the dragging part a definite requirement? Or would it be acceptable to, for example, click on the event, show a pop-up, and then select staff members from a list, or drop-down, or even drag them into a separate draggable target in the pop-up? You _might_ be able to make an event a draggable target directly (it's just a HTML element, after all), but I haven't tried it. have you researched or tried anything yet?

Comment: Dragging is definitely a requirement. What I've managed to do so far is only allow dragging on to the main calendar from a certain class (the date period shift), and then on eventRender I've added an external droppable event to the element which accepts the staff members. Haven't tied anything up with it yet but this is definitely the way to go I think!

Comment: Great. If you manage to get a usable solution, post it as an Answer below, as I think other people might find this concept useful!

Comment: Done! Hopefully will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get this working using jQuery draggable. So firstly I told fullcalendar to only accept internal drag events from a specific class (so I can drag in time slots into the calendar):

`dropAccept: ".PresetShift"`

And then on eventRender, I make the event droppable (so I can drop in the crew members/staff members):

```
   $(element).droppable({
        scope: "staff",
        hoverClass: "highlighted",
        drop: function(dropEvent, ui) {
            //Get data from event, attributes from the dropped in staff member, and the 
            event and use a page method to save/update the data. 
            Then update the fullcalendar event
        }
    });
},
```